# wkhtmltopdf internal links

Tags: hyperlink, indexing, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf to generate reports from my html templates, i am trying to generate an index for the output PDF.

The thing is that I want to achieve similar functionality to the indexes of microsoft word.

For this purpose I need to use several internal links among the document, so when clicking in the index of the PDF, it goes to page 10 for example.

Any clues about how to achieve this?

I am using wkhtmltopdf version 0.11.0 rc2 in Windows, but sooner or later I will have to move it to linux so I need a compatible solution among operating systems.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the solution by my self, but i just haven't check compatibility with Linux.

For achieving the internal links you add in the html:

**Target of the Link:**

```
 <a name="name_of_target">Content</a>
```

**Link to the Target:**

```
 <a href="#name_of_target">Link Text</a>
```

It works perfectly when converted to pdf.

Comment: Yep, that's the classic way to make internal links in HTML. In wkhtmltopdf, keep in mind though that if you edit the PDF (add/remove pages for example) the link might get broken.

Comment: I have noticed it since I am adding a front page later. So in order to solve this I added an empty page at the begining and replace it later with the front page, doing this I got the links to still work after modification.

Comment: There's an option to do a cover from a separate HTML file as well in wkhtmltopdf, using the `cover /path/to/cover.html` option. I use that but it does limit the usage a little, since wkhtmltopdf doesn't really handle complex layouts very well.

Comment: I need to create a PDF by merging multple existing PDFs and adding a toc at the beginning, To have a target for the toc links I create dummy pages with only the targets on and remove all but the first page before merging. It seems it works, in the sense that it jumps to the right pages, even though the targets will gone after merging. My question now is, do I need to worry that I create an inconsistent PDF document that might fail in some readers?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with wkhtmltopdf

```
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt)
```

with debian 9 installed with the package.

```
wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1_linux-jessie-amd64.deb
```

I enabled the internal links with the command option

```
--enable-internal-links
```

I used the target:

```
 <a name="name_of_target"><div><img src="image.png">Content</div></a>
```

and the link

```
 <a href="#name_of_target">Link Text</a>
```

But still not working, other link in the document worked well.
Then I replaced the div with a span and it worked.

```
 <a name="name_of_target"><span><img src="image.png">Content</span></a>
```

The issue is related with the *display block* rule of div elements. When I added *display block* rule to the span the link not worked again.

Answer (score 2):

It can be tricky. E.g. invisible (empty) links don't work as targets. Also, the structure seems to matter and not all valid html5 layouts work. E.g. I found that while this works:

```
<h2><a name="name_of_target">Target</a></h2>
```

this does not:

```
<a name="name_of_target"><h2>Target</h2></a>
```

Despite both being perfectly valid (in html5). (I'm using version 0.12.6.)